# Difficulty reading and writing binary files

Tags: vb.net, binary

My code works on my 64-bit machine but I encounter the following error (occasionally the code works fine however) when running it on a 32-bit machine:

InvalidCastException was unhandled

The next few lines provide my code:

To write to the binary file:

```vb
Dim  writeStream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)
Dim BinReader As BinaryReader

next_byte = Len(CStr(time)) + Len("EndOfHeader") + 16 + 2
first_time = True

BinWriter = New BinaryWriter(writeStream)

For i = 0 To Form1.signals.Length - 1
    If IsNothing(Form1.signals(i)) = False Then
        'once for each test
        BinWriter.Write(Int(Form1.signals(i).picodata.GetLength(0) - 1)) 'n for each signal in test
        BinWriter.Write(Form1.signals(i).picodata(1, 0) - Form1.signals(i).picodata(0, 0)) 'timestep
        BinWriter.Write(next_byte) 'position of start of test
        BinWriter.Write(CStr(time))
        Exit For
    End If
Next

BinWriter.Write("EndOfHeader")

For i = 0 To Form1.signals.Length - 1
    If IsNothing(Form1.signals(i)) = False Then
        BinWriter.Write(i)
            For j = 1 To Form1.signals(i).picodata.GetLength(0) - 1
                BinWriter.Write(Form1.signals(i).picodata(j, 1))
        Next
    End If
Next

BinWriter.Close()
```

To read in:

```vb
Dim readstream As FileStream
Dim end_test As Integer
Dim Index As Integer
Dim BinReader As BinaryReader
Dim end_head as Boolean=false        
Dim count as integer=0

selected_test=0

ReadStream = New FileStream(readFileName, FileMode.Open)
BinReader = New BinaryReader(ReadStream)

'read header
While end_head = False
    Try
        pos_old = ReadStream.Position
        try_string = BinReader.ReadString
        If try_string = "EndOfHeader" Then
            Exit While
        Else
            ReadStream.Position = pos_old
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ReadStream.Position = pos_old
    End Try


    'this approach allows for flexibility 
    number_arr(count) = BinReader.ReadInt32
    TimeStep_arr(count) = BinReader.ReadDouble
    position_arr(count) = BinReader.ReadInt32
    time_arr(count) = CDate(BinReader.ReadString)
    count += 1
End While

'read in data
While readstream.Position <> read_stream.length
    ReDim PicoData(number_arr(selected_test), 1)
    Index = BinReader.ReadInt32
    n = number_arr(selected_test)

    For i = 1 To n
        PicoData(i, 1) = BinReader.ReadDouble
        PicoData(i, 0) = TimeStep_arr(selected_test) * i
    Next

    ReDim TimeShort(Int(n / 20))
    ReDim FiltVoltsShort(Int(n / 20))
    ReDim FiltVelShort(Int(n / 20))
    ReDim RawVoltsShort(Int(n / 20))

    'generate new reading here
    Call FourierFilter(PicoData, 0)

    signals(Index) = New reading(Index, TimeShort, RawVoltsShort, FiltVelShort, FiltVoltsShort, Points_Store(ii, 2), Points_Store(ii, 1), DataChart, VelocityChart, SelectedTimeBox, SelectedVelocityBox, True, PicoData)

End While


BinReader.Close()
readstream.Close()
```

The date occasionally is not read in correctly. I will get some character + the date I want. Parts of my code have been cut out (since the program is pretty huge) but hopefully what I have sent will make some sense. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide details about your calculation of next_byte? That might be involved in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step should be to find a simple-as-possible reproducible test case where you can make it fail every time. Then it will be much easier to identify the source of the problem.

Code like this might help you narrow down how BinaryWriter encodes strings on different platforms.

```
Dim content As String = New String("!"c, 255)
Using outStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
   Using bw As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(outStream)
      bw.Write(content)
      bw.Flush()
      outStream.Flush()
      Console.WriteLine("I am a " & If(Environment.Is64BitProcess, "64", "32") & _
          "-bit process")
      Console.WriteLine("I generated a string of {0} characters into a stream " & _
          "of {1} bytes", content.Length, outStream.Length)
   End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I have been attempting this, however the error appears to happen randomly. It must be an issue with how items are written to the file because copying the generated file over to my other machine (which seems to handle everything fine by itself) I get the same error. I write an integer, followed by a double, followed by an integer and then a str - the numeric data types are read in correctly, however things fall down when the string is read in (the string is converted from a date and written to the file but when read in I occasionally get a character leading the string which shouldn't be there)

Comment: As I experiment with BinaryWriter strings I find that it often only writes a prefix of 1 byte. I am continuing to investigate. How long is your problem string?

Comment: I see now that the length prefix on a string written to a BinaryWriter is a UTF-7 encoded integer. How long is your problem string? I have added some test code to my answer that might help collect some helpful information. I suggest you do some more focused testing on the exact bytes that are in the file to figure out where exactly the problem starts. Is it the writer that's bad or the reader? Examining a very small test file that reproduces the problem (if you can create one) should make it possible to identify it manually with the help of a binary editor.

Comment: I too just found this out. I am using cstr(datetime.now) and so any problem strings will be the same length as accepted strings. I'm not sure why this prefix is being included in the string read in.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that if you could just isolate a small problem file example I could tell you what's happening; the real challenge is to find that repeatable example.

Comment: The following segment of my binary file contains this error:

j  {®GázÄ?2   10/15/2013 4:23:25 PMEndOfHeader

The following segment is from a successful file:

j  {®GázÄ?2   10/15/2013 4:22:55 PMEndOfHeader 

I cant see what would be causing this issue.

Comment: arghh sorry,. Some characters can't be represented